# React native Twitter Signin release build issue

Tags: react-native, twitter

I am using the *react-native-twitter-signin* plugin for twitter login in iOS, but I am not able to build the *release build* in iOS as it shows:

Apple Mach o- linker issue:

```
/Documents/Example-fnshwaxexazdtybaedpmgfxfynrx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Example/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libRNTwitterSignIn.a
```

The same application is running perfectly in *Debug Mode* on iOS:
I have already linked the **libRNTwitterSignin.a** under **linked binary with libraries**

Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

Comment: Check whether **header search paths** in *build settings* are same for both debug and release mode.

Comment: @ArpitKapadia yes it is same in both the debug & release mode

Comment: please check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, finally did like below.
please add **RNTwitterSignIn** to **Target Dependences** of **build phases**.
It will fix that.